# Selenium: Java VM keeps crashing whilest running Webdriver tests in IE 6/7

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm running a series of selenium test suites in Java following a JUnit format and when running.

The tests run successfully when I run them on a machine with IE 8/9 and Firefox 14 however when running on a machine with IE6/7 the Java VM crashes at random intervals during the tests and I have no idea why.

After some googling this issue seems to have been encountered before and the recommended fix was generally to upgrade to selenium 2.24.1 and add IEDriverServer.exe to the classpath.

I have done both of these and it has made no difference.

Test setup:
The tests are called with an ANT script using the JUnit command. I'm having to support some older selenium RC tests which have been converted to Webdriver backed tests.

Error from the JUnitreport:
Forked Java VM exited abnormally. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the VM exit.

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Forked Java VM exited abnormally. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the VM exit.
at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)

If you need anymore info please let me know.

Regards
Crimson

Comment: No repro on Win XP SP3, IE6, Java 7u5, Selenium 2.24.1 (btw, 2.25.0 got out today, try it out). What was your config, again? The only thing I didn't try yet is to run it via Ant, I'll try that tommorow. Is it stabĺe on your side, too, if ran manually?